# I have a problem in running angular application due to dependencies?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am developing an angular application using ngrx, i have installed the dependencies but when running the app i am getting some errors which related to version mismatch

See the below errors which i got when compiling it

```
ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts (30,31): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (23,154): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (24,178): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (25,171): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/effects_metadata.d.ts (2,19): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/effects_metadata.d.ts (11,13): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/actions.d.ts (2,22): Module '"J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'OperatorFunction'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/actions.d.ts (28,42): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/actions.d.ts (31,42): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/actions.d.ts (34,42): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/actions.d.ts (37,42): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/actions.d.ts (40,42): Cannot find name 'Extract'.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/effects_module.d.ts (5,53): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

ERROR in J:/Official/16-01-2019/ngx-admin-dashboard/ngx-admin-dashboard-master/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/effects_module.d.ts (6,47): Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.
webpack: Failed to compile.

Here is my package.json dependencies

"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "material-design-iconic-font": "^2.2.0",
    "ng-selectize": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.8",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "selectize": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

Can anyone please check and let me know if any wrong in versions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Angular to version 7 or downgrade NgRx to version 5.